# How can I write something in a box with \makeemptybox{1.8in}?

Tags: exam

I would like to write something in a box with `\makeemptybox{1.8in}`? I am using the `\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}`.

Thank you.

Comment: You're posting a lot of questions but hardly accept any answers to them. This leaves the impression of disregarding the users willing to help you

Comment: I read with attention the answers and I appreciate anyone who wants help me.

Comment: That's not really how `TeX.SX` works: Appreciating is giving feedback, upvoting and accepting.

Answer (score 5):

You could define a `\makenonemptybox` macro:

```
\documentclass[addpoints]{exam}

\newcommand{\makenonemptybox}[2]{%
  \par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent
  \fbox{%
    \parbox[c][\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{
      \hrule width \hsize height 0pt
      #2
    }%
  }%
  \par\vspace{\ht\strutbox}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{questions}
\question
  In no more than one paragraph, explain why the earth is round.
  \makeemptybox{1in}

\question
  \begin{parts}
  \part
    What changes to the van Allen radiation belt are needed to make
    the earth into a regular icosahedron?
    \makenonemptybox{1in}{(Hint: try splitting hairs)}
  \part
    Where should the field generator be constructed if you want one of
    the vertices to be located at the Royal Observatory at Greenwich?
    \makeemptybox{1in}
  \end{parts}
\end{questions}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is great! Is there any way to make it work with `\vspace{\stretch{1}}`?