# How can I write in a box with fixed height?

Tags: box

I am using `report` class and have been using `\framebox[\linewidth]{\rule{0pt}{2cm}}` to create an empty box with a certain height. Now, I would like to write in that empty box. By referring to [How can I write something in a box with \makeemptybox{1.8in}?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/308458/how-can-i-write-something-in-a-box-with-makeemptybox1-8in), I achieved the following:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\newcommand{\makenonemptybox}[2]{%
\par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent
\fbox{%
\parbox[c][\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep}{
  \hrule width \hsize height 0pt
  #2
 }%
}%
\par\vspace{\ht\strutbox}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Tell me about yourself.
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item What is your name?
    \makenonemptybox{2cm}{My name is Nadia.}
    \item Where are you from?
    \makenonemptybox{2cm}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam a venenatis lacus. Nunc vitae mollis neque. Maecenas vel arcu erat.}
    \item How old are you?
    \item[] \framebox[\linewidth]{\rule{0pt}{2cm}}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

As you can see `\makenoemptybox` makes a bigger vertical space compared to `\framebox` (refer to the coloured arrows). How can I make the vertical space made by `\makenoemptybox` follows that of `\framebox`?

[image]

Comment: Related Question: [mdframed box of fixed minimum height](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/125645/4301).

Comment: Perhaps I am missing something, but if you just want an empty box of the same size, why not just use `\makenonemptybox{2cm}{}`?

Comment: @PeterGrill I've just edited the picture.

Comment: side remark: as got clarified later the `\parbox[c][\dimexpr#1-2\fboxsep]` in `\makenonemptybox` should have been `\parbox[c][#1]` to start with, because when `\framebox[\linewidth]{\rule{0pt}{2cm}}` is used the total height is 2cm +  `2\fboxsep` + `2\fboxrule`. To do the same with `\makenonemptybox` for the height it thus should be  `\parbox[c][#1]` when `#1` is `2cm`. Besides, removing `\fboxsep` makes no sense if not removing also `\fboxrule`, then total height including frame and separation would be `2cm`. But  `\framebox[\linewidth]{\rule{0pt}{2cm}}` gives `2cm+2\fboxsep+2\fboxrule`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use in the definition of `\makenonemptybox` the same method you use for `\framebox` to close current paragraph. Of course, that will restrict its usage to list environments.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}

\newcommand{\makenonemptybox}[2]{%
%\par\nobreak\vspace{\ht\strutbox}\noindent
\item[]
\fbox{% added -2\fboxrule to specified width to avoid overfull hboxes
% and removed the -2\fboxsep from height specification (image not updated)
% because in MWE 2cm is should be height of contents excluding sep and frame
\parbox[c][#1][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}{
  \hrule width \hsize height 0pt
  #2
 }%
}%
\par\vspace{\ht\strutbox}
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Tell me about yourself.
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item What is your name?
          \makenonemptybox{2cm}{My name is Nadia.}
    \item Where are you from?
          \makenonemptybox{2cm}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam a venenatis lacus. Nunc vitae mollis neque. Maecenas vel arcu erat.}
    \item How old are you?
    \item[] \framebox[\linewidth]{\rule{0pt}{2cm}}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: you could also drop the `\item[]` from the macro definition and use it explicitely as input mark-up like you do before the `\framebox`. Then the macro could be used in other contexts, with some adapted prefix such as a `\par`.

Comment: Why does `\makenonemptybox` give me overfull \hbox?

Comment: @Nadia because the original code forgot to reduce width by `2\fboxrule`. I will add that.

Comment: Added also `-2\fboxrule` to height specification.

Comment: wait.... why are `2\fboxsep` removed from height specs to start with? they should not because `2cm` is used by the `\rule` in `\framebox`. I will remove them (and the `2\fboxrule` I temporarily added)

Answer (score 0):

A \par and a `minipage` works:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,11pt]{report}
\newcommand{\makenonemptybox}[2]{%
\par{\fboxsep1ex\fbox{%
\begin{minipage}[c][#1][t]{\dimexpr\linewidth-2\fboxsep-2\fboxrule}%
#2\end{minipage}}}}}%
\begin{document}
\begin{enumerate}
\item Tell me about yourself.
    \begin{enumerate}
    \item What is your name?
    \makenonemptybox{2cm}{My name is Nadia.}
    \item Where are you from?
    \makenonemptybox{2cm}{Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nullam a venenatis lacus. Nunc vitae mollis neque. Maecenas vel arcu erat.}
    \item How old are you?
    \item[] \framebox[\linewidth]{\rule{0pt}{2cm}}
    \end{enumerate}
\end{enumerate}
\end{document}
```